# How to replicate a distorted cartoony look and slimy title effect?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, text, photoshop-effects, drawing

I'd like to replicate this title card from *Adventure Time*, and I'd like to know how I can achieve that distorted VHS-ish retro-ish glitchy-blurry scratchy look. If you're feeling extra helpful: how can I get that fabulously slimy text effect? I only have Photoshop CS6 to play with.

[image]

Comment: What have you tried? What worked and what didn't? I'm not 100% clear what particular effects you want,

Comment: This is not especially scratchy or blurry at least when seeing its low resolution. The opposite: It seems to be quite a pice of high quality work! Put your own trial to visible and point the details that you want to have something from the model image. "All" is a wrong answer because for that exists "Copy"

Comment: i mean like the grain on the whole illustration and the scratches at the edges that make it look like it has a ripped paper texture, there's a vignette i think? and there are small circle shaped particles covering the whole pic. you can see it better on this pic: http://vignette2.wikia.nocookie.net/adventuretimewithfinnandjake/images/3/38/Titlecard_S1E1_slumberpartypanic.png/revision/latest?cb=20120822151924

Comment: And by the way there's nothing VHS in these textures, these are specifically seen in printed pieces. VHS distortion looks quite different https://www.google.com/search?q=vhs+glitch&tbm=isch

Answer (score 0):

I would say for the vhs/retro effect try experimenting with the halftone filter (filter->pixelate->Colour halftone), maybe lowering the saturation slightly and adding noise (filter->noise->add noise). Also add a little bit of blur to it, this together with the halftone effect will give you the "glitchy-blurry" look.

Only thing i can add to that is you will have to have the right type of artwork to get the desired effect.